# empty fields to be filled with previous values

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, numpy, interpolation

[image]

In the above sample data, I have empty fields and now the task is to fill the fields with previous values.
my columns are dates and the values are a number of items present for that particular article for the specific date.
which would be a faster way to interpolate the missing fields. Any suggestions to build the function is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function with [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) method:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I converted my empty fields with df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True,inplace=True) and applied df.fillna. But still have some values which has nan

Comment: What do they look like? Do they have any value preceding them or are they the first value in the column?

Comment: it occurs only with the first row and there is no preceding to it.

Comment: That is the reason, ffill uses the previous value to fill the next. First row has nothing before it so it cannot be filled by this method. I thought that was the what you wanted?

Comment: im so stupid, my apologies, I wanted to fill it with the previous values. not the above values. for example, the article LL-23896 has nan need to fill them with 0 and the next values to be interpolated. I hope i was clear.

Comment: in that case, you need to use "df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True). Replace "ffill" method with "bfill".